# Refreshing a JTable that contains JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with cells that render a JPanel. The problem is that everytime I update the model, the JTable doesn't fire. My current code is below. I tried different things such as table.validate() and table.repaint() but still doesn't refresh the table.

I tried to change the table's model by doing table.setModel(newModel) but this completely wipes off the table (including the deselecting). I would prefer the table to update silently in the background.

The refresh code works very well on my other default rendered JTable but this doesn't work on this particular one.

```
public class RoomViewTable2 {
    JScrollPane hostPane;
    public static JTable table;
    public static DefaultTableModel model;
    private static Timer refreshTimer;

public RoomViewTable2() {

}

public static JTable getRoomViewTable() {
    model = new RoomRowTableModel(getFeeds());
    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(TablePanelUI.class, new RoomRowCellRenderer());
    table.setRowHeight(75);

    runRefreshTimer();

    return table;
}

public static ArrayList<TablePanelUI> getFeeds() {
    ArrayList<TablePanelUI> feeds = new ArrayList<TablePanelUI>();
    try {
        DB.dbConnect();
        String sql = "SELECT id, folio_id from room_view WHERE validity = '1'";
        ResultSet rs = DB.con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE
                , ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
                .executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            feeds.add(new TablePanelUI(new RoomInfo(rs.getInt(1))
                , new FolioInfo(rs.getInt(2))));
        }
        rs.close();
        DB.con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return feeds;
}

public static class RoomRowCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer{
      public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        TablePanelUI room = (TablePanelUI) value;

        JPanel panel = room.getPanel();

        if (isSelected) {
          panel.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        }else{
          panel.setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }

        return panel;
      }
}

public static void refreshRoomView() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            model = new RoomRowTableModel(getFeeds());
            model.fireTableDataChanged();
            table.updateUI();   
        }
    });

}

public static void runRefreshTimer() {
    refreshTimer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            refreshRoomView();
            System.out.println("UPDATING");
        }
    });
    refreshTimer.start();
}

public static class RoomRowTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    ArrayList<TablePanelUI> feeds;

    public RoomRowTableModel(ArrayList<TablePanelUI> feeds) {
        this.feeds = feeds;
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) { 
        return TablePanelUI.class; 
    }

    public int getColumnCount() { 
        return 1; 
    }

    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) { 
        return "Feed"; 
    }

    public int getRowCount() { 
        return (feeds == null) ? 0 : feeds.size(); 
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) { 
        return (feeds == null) ? null : feeds.get(rowIndex); 
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int columnIndex, int rowIndex) { 
        return true; 
    }
}
```

**EDITED: Solution to the problem above**

As suggested by @JB Nizet

1.) Added setFeed() to the DefaultTableModel

```
    public void setFeed(ArrayList<TablePanelUI> feeds) {
        this.feeds = feeds;
    }
```

2.) Refreshed the model's feed and fired the event

```
int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
model.setFeed(getFeeds());
model.fireTableDataChanged();
table.updateUI();
if (selectedRow >= 0) {
    table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, selectedRow);  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start by creating a model, and a table using this model:

```
table --uses--> model --contains--> data
```

But when you want to refresh the table, instead of updating this model and make the model fire an event so that the table re-reads the model and updates its view, you create another different model, and you make this new model fire an event:

```
table --uses--> model --contains--> data 

                newModel --contains--> newData
```

But the table still uses the previous model, and thus doesn't receive any event. And even if it did, it would still re-read the data frm the model it uses, not from the new model you created.

You must create a *single* model, update it (i.e. change its feeds), and fire the appropriate events from this model.

Comment: Hi JB, I think I understand what you are saying and that is what I wanted to achieve but I need a bit more help. In my refreshRoomView() method above, I believe I updated the single model I assigned to the table by providing it a new feed. (i.e. new RoomRowTableModel(getFeeds());) and I told the model to fire the event. Did I do it the wrong way?

Comment: You're not updating the existing model. You're creating a new model. and assigning it to the same variable. That's completely different. To update the existing model, you need to do `model.setFeeds(getFeeds());`

Comment: Ohh!!! So that's why!!! I figured it out now -- it worked like a charm. I'll post my edited code with your suggestion. Thanks a lot man!